# When I run Google AIY program I got an error

Tags: python

when i test a demo.py( actually the official support: assistant_library_demo.py )
the python program take me to a website like below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHkQV.png)

when i enter in：

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IaGd.png)

when i click the allow button，i got an error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2oS6.png)

code below：

```
import logging
import platform
import sys

from google.assistant.library.event import EventType

from aiy.assistant import auth_helpers
from aiy.assistant.library import Assistant
from aiy.board import Board, Led

def process_event(led, event):
    logging.info(event)

    if event.type == EventType.ON_START_FINISHED:
        led.state = Led.BEACON_DARK  # Ready.
        logging.info('Say "OK, Google" then speak, or press Ctrl+C to quit...')

    elif event.type == EventType.ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_STARTED:
        led.state = Led.ON  # Listening.

    elif event.type == EventType.ON_END_OF_UTTERANCE:
        led.state = Led.PULSE_QUICK  # Thinking.

    elif (event.type == EventType.ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_FINISHED
          or event.type == EventType.ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_TIMEOUT
          or event.type == EventType.ON_NO_RESPONSE):
        led.state = Led.BEACON_DARK

    elif event.type == EventType.ON_ASSISTANT_ERROR and event.args and event.args['is_fatal']:
        sys.exit(1)


def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    credentials = auth_helpers.get_assistant_credentials()
    with Board() as board, Assistant(credentials) as assistant:
        for event in assistant.start():
            process_event(board.led, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Post the related code in your question.

Comment: ok, i show it below